# How to access Erlang shell JCL Mode inside an Emacs inferior-erlang shell?

Tags: comint, erlang-mode

Inside an Erlang shell one can access the Erlang shell User Switch Command menu (also called [Erlang shell JCL Mode](https://erlang.org/doc/man/shell.html#jcl-mode)) by typing *Ctrl-G*.

When running the Erlang shell inside Emacs (as an inferior-erlang) typing `C-g` once or twice or any other number of times does not bring the menu.  Inside a comint driven shell, one can type `C-c C-c` to generate a *Ctrl-C* for the Erlang shell process. I did not find something similar to generate a *Ctrl-G*.  Is there something?

*Environment:* Running Erlang 24 on macOS Mojave.  Running Emacs 26.3 or 27.2 either graphical app or in termcap mode on a macOS Terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After further research I found a way: type `C-q C-g RET`.

That opens the Erlang shell JCL Mode.

The `C-q` key is bound to `(quoted-insert ARG)` allowing to pass the *Ctrl-G* once a `RET` is typed.